# Some explaination about C++ code (lambda wrapper and variadic template)

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-templates

Can someone explain to me what does this piece of code step by step? I found it in this topic : [Segmentation fault on gcc caused by lambda wrapper over variadic template function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40618339/segmentation-fault-on-gcc-caused-by-lambda-wrapper-over-variadic-template-functi) and I don't understand nothing :

```
template <typename TNode, typename... TNodes>
auto execute(TNode& n, TNodes&... ns)
    {      
        [&](){ n.execute(ns...); }();
    }
```

Especially the part : `[&](){ n.execute(ns...); }();`

Is there any connection with lambda calculus and programmation language like caml or ocaml?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part `[&](){ n.execute(ns...); }();` creates a new lambda and execute it directly. It is equal to:

```
auto temp= [&](){ n.execute(ns...); };
temp();
```

This part  `n.execute(ns...);` is calling a member function called `TNode::execute` which accepts many parameters (variadic template argument) of the types `TNodes...`